# what is audio PCM's frame sync word to identify the beginning position

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pcm, multimedia

As title; for some compressed format such as EAC3, AC3 frame starts as a sync word.

So what's PCM (raw audio)'s sync word? How to identify the beginning of a PCM frame?

I met a problem where audio is concatenated by several audio segments and each of them has different frame size. I need to identify the start position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept as a frame in PCM. The concept of a frame is to indicate points of random access. In PCM every single sample is a point of random access, hence start indicators are not required, and there are no standard frame size. It all up to you.

Answer (score 1):

A PCM frame is different from the frames you're describing, in that a frame is just a single sample on all channels.  That is, if I'm recording 16-bit stereo PCM audio, each frame is 4 bytes (32 bits) long.

There is no sync word, nor frame header in raw PCM.  It's just a stream of data.  You need to know the bit depth, channel count, and current offset if you want to sync to it.  (Or, you need to do some simple heuristics.  For example, apply several different formats and offsets to a small chunk of data and see which one has the least variance/randomness from sample to sample.)